# Python: Drop rows from dataframe based multiple criteria

Tags: python, pandas, duplicates, data-migration

I'm fairly new to Python and have inherited some Python scripts to tidy up a CSV dump files from old software system for import into new system.  I have a large dataframe of persons and I need to extract a subset of this dataframe for related persons and tidy it up by removing nulls, non-existing persons and paired matches.

A function has been written to perform this task but when run only a small number of rows are being removed with many paired-matches and non-existing persons remaining.  Can someone please help me locate where this is going wrong?

The function has been defined as follows:

```py
def extract_relations(df):
    fields = ['REF', 'PERSON',
              'RELATED_PERSON', 'RELATED_CODE']
    df = df[fields].copy()
    nan_value = float("NaN")
    df.replace('', nan_value, inplace=True)
    all_customers = df['PERSON'].astype(str).tolist()
    df.dropna(subset=['RELATED_PERSON'], inplace=True)
    rel_customers = df['RELATED_PERSON'].astype(str).tolist()

     # For each row in the dataframe
    for idx, row in df.iterrows():
        # Split the string by double-colon
        splitrel = re.split(':{2}', df.at[idx, 'RELATED_PERSON'])
        splitcode = re.split(':{2}', df.at[idx, 'RELATED_CODE'])

        # for each related person number
        for i in splitrel:
            # check if the related person has already been covered
            # on the list previously with mirroring relation
            exists = str(i) in rel_customers[:idx]
            # check if the related member is the same as the member
            same = str(i) == str(df.at[idx, 'PERSON'])
            # check if the related member is a member being migrated
            active = str(i) not in all_customers

            # if any of the above are true, remove the relation number and code 
            if exists or same or active:
                lstindex = splitrel.index(i)
                splitrel.pop(lstindex)
                splitcode.pop(lstindex)
                #del splitrel[lstindex]
                #del splitcode[lstindex]
                
            # Join concatenanted rows back up
            df.at[idx, 'RELATED_PERSON'] = '::'.join(splitrel)
            df.at[idx, 'RELATED_CODE'] = '::'.join(splitcode)

        # If no relations remain, drop the row
        if df.at[idx, 'RELATED_PERSON'] == '':
            df = df.drop(idx)
```

I have redacted the code writing the resulting dataframe out to .txt file but after reviewing the output this it appears the majority of the rows that are in "exists or same or active" are not being dropped.  Also, some valid entries are being removed.  I expected my dataframe to be about 50% smaller than it actually is!

Note: I've tried "del splitrel" instead of "splitrel.pop" (commented out within the if statement) but it made no difference to the output.

I've read online that removing items in this manner can result in "shifting" of the dataframe as the row/index number you are removing is subsequently changed however the sheer number of rows not removed has me thinking this is not the issue here.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

As requested, a copy-paste of code to create sample dataframe is below:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({'REF':'NK213','PERSON':[18,20,91,92,95,105,122,138,323,324,14208,14871,14984,15902,19253,35378,37580,47225,201391],'RELATED_PERSON':['14208','14871','14984','105','15071','','14016','136','324','323','','','','9995','19253::47225','35378','38181::38461::38462','','201391'],'RELATED_CODE':['2','2','2','2','2','','2','2','2','2','','','','2','6::6','6','6::6::6','','6']})
```

**Output after running function is:**

| REF | PERSON | RELATED_PERSON | RELATED_CODE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| NK213 | 18 | 14208 | 2 |
| NK213 | 20 | 14871 | 2 |
| NK213 | 91 | 14984 | 2 |
| NK213 | 92 | 105 | 2 |
| NK213 | 19253 | 47225 | 6 |
| NK213 | 37580 | 38461 | 6 |

**Expected:**

1. The last row should not have been returned as Person 38461 does not exist.
2. One of the following "matching pairs" should have been retained in the output but both were removed.

| REF | PERSON | RELATED_PERSON | RELATED_CODE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| NK213 | 323 | 324 | 2 |
| NK213 | 324 | 323 | 2 |

Comment: It would help potential answerers a lot if you could provide a copy-pastable sample input dataframe along with desired output.

Comment: Updated to include code for a test dataframe @Seb

Answer (score 0):

Dear sir or madam dms_paul,

I am afraid that I had some trouble trying to understand what were the multiple criteria needed in order to generate the desired dataframe. In this sense, I suppose that you wish to generate a table of persons, each of which has at least one related person that is present in the 'PERSON' column of the table itself, with the condition that the related person is not themself.

Should this be the case, I hope that the following code can be of help.

Input:

| index | REF | PERSON | RELATED_PERSON | RELATED_CODE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | NK213 | 18 | 14208 | 2 |
| 1 | NK213 | 20 | 14871 |  |
| 2 | NK213 | 91 | 14984 | 2 |
| 3 | NK213 | 92 | 105 | 2 |
| 4 | NK213 | 95 | 15071 | 2 |
| 5 | NK213 | 105 |  |  |
| 6 | NK213 | 122 | 14016 | 2 |
| 7 | NK213 | 138 | 136 | 2 |
| 8 | NK213 | 323 | 324 | 2 |
| 9 | NK213 | 324 | 323 | 2 |
| 10 | NK213 | 14208 |  |  |
| 11 | NK213 | 14871 |  |  |
| 12 | NK213 | 14984 |  |  |
| 13 | NK213 | 15902 | 9995 | 2 |
| 14 | NK213 | 19253 | 19253::47225 | 6::6 |
| 15 | NK213 | 35378 | 35378 | 6 |
| 16 | NK213 | 37580 | 38181::38461::38462 | 6::6::6 |
| 17 | NK213 | 47225 |  |  |
| 18 | NK213 | 201391 | 201391 | 6 |

Code:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'REF':'NK213','PERSON':[18,20,91,92,95,105,122,138,323,324,14208,14871,14984,15902,19253,35378,37580,47225,201391],'RELATED_PERSON':['14208','14871','14984','105','15071','','14016','136','324','323','','','','9995','19253::47225','35378','38181::38461::38462','','201391'],'RELATED_CODE':['2','2','2','2','2','','2','2','2','2','','','','2','6::6','6','6::6::6','','6']})

def extract_relations(dataframe):
    
    fields = ['REF', 'PERSON',
              'RELATED_PERSON', 'RELATED_CODE']
    
    df = dataframe[fields].copy()

    #Up to this point, the code is most similar to what you have posted.
    #We first generate a list of related persons with corresponding code.
    
    df['RELATED_PERSON']=df['RELATED_PERSON'].str.split("::")
    df['RELATED_CODE']=df['RELATED_CODE'].str.split("::")

    #Expand rows of persons with related persons.

    df = df.explode(['RELATED_PERSON','RELATED_CODE'],ignore_index=True)

    #Filter the rows in order to consider only the cases 
    #where the related person is in the 'PERSON' column.
    
    df = df[df['RELATED_PERSON'].isin(df['PERSON'].astype('str'))]

    #Filter the rows in order to consider only the cases 
    #where the related person is not the same as the person in consideration.
    
    df = df[df['RELATED_PERSON'] != df['PERSON'].astype('str')]
    
    return df.reset_index(drop=True)

extract_relations(df)
```

Output:

| index | REF | PERSON | RELATED_PERSON | RELATED_CODE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | NK213 | 18 | 14208 | 2 |
| 1 | NK213 | 20 | 14871 | 2 |
| 2 | NK213 | 91 | 14984 | 2 |
| 3 | NK213 | 92 | 105 | 2 |
| 4 | NK213 | 323 | 324 | 2 |
| 5 | NK213 | 324 | 323 | 2 |
| 6 | NK213 | 19253 | 47225 | 6 |

Yours faithfully,

Luís Martins.